# 16.10 not seeing USB WiFi device on startup

Tags: networking, usb

After update to 16.10 not seeing on startup plugged USB WiFi device. To make it see the wifi adapter I have to manually replug the USB cabel and then it start working. This is a syslog after replug

```
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk kernel: [  319.718918] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd  
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk kernel: [  319.876121] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070  
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk kernel: [  319.876123] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3  
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk kernel: [  319.876124] usb 1-8: Product: 802.11 n WLAN  
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk kernel: [  319.876126] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Ralink  
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk kernel: [  319.876126] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 1.0  
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8" 
Nov  5 05:39:50 vv0iadyk mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device  
Nov  5 05:39:51 vv0iadyk kernel: [  321.411210] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd    
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk kernel: [  321.561519] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3070, rev 0201 detected  
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk URfkill[1572]: adding killswitch type 1 idx 0 soft 0 hard 0  
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk URfkill[1572]: Setting device 0 (WLAN) to unblocked  
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk kernel: [  321.571177] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0005 detected  
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...    
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk URfkill[1572]: set_soft: Setting WLAN to unblocked    
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk NetworkManager[1713]: <info>  [1478317192.0596] (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control    
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk kernel: [  321.597737] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'  
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk kernel: [  321.598889] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb  
Nov  5 05:39:52 vv0iadyk kernel: [  321.601181] rt2800usb 1-8:1.0 wlxe***********: renamed from wlan0
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 I rarely had to manually replug this device to make it work but on 16.10 I need to do it every time when turn on the pc,though on restarts this device working without replug. How to make it work without
replug on start up?

Comment: Would a modproobe rt2800usb  do ?